# Timeout expire error when to insert data into table and simultaneously select query running on same table in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

I have one main table and another details table. And the tables have primary and foreign key relationship. But when I want to insert data into main table and another select query is running in SQL Server which fetches data from both tables, at this moment while inserting data in main table I am getting "Timeout expired" errors.

Please suggest an answer.

Comment: The symptoms suggest a common blocking scenario. Perhaps query and index tuning will help. Not enough information in your question to be more specific or provide a good answer.

Comment: Thanks for reply.

Comment: I have working on a windows application. 'PropertyMaster' is primary key table and 'Propertydetails' is another table and this table have foreign key. Form in windows application has code which execute update query to update some data. At this moment if I have been executing any select on which fetches data from both tables then C# code gives me error of "TImeout expired".

Comment: How long does it take for the queries to run? You should add the table DDL (including indexes) along with the `SELECT` and `UPDATE` queries to your question if you need help with tuning. It seems either the `SELECT` and `UPDATE` queries are locking more data than needed.

Comment: SELECT query takes one minute to run and UPDATE query takes max one second to run.

Comment: My table definitions are as follows,                                                    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PropertyMast](
 [OwnerID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [NewZoneNo] [nvarchar](30) NOT NULL,
 [NewWardNo] [nvarchar](30) NOT NULL,
 [NewPropertyNo] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
 
 CONSTRAINT [PK_DataEntry] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [OwnerID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PropertyDetailsNew](
 [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [OwnerID] [int] NOT NULL,
 [FloorID] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_NewPropertyDetails] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
([ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PropertyDetailsNew]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_PropertyDetailsNew_PropertyMast] FOREIGN KEY([OwnerID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[PropertyMast] ([OwnerID])

Comment: Please add the DDL to your question rather than as comments along with query examples. The tables have no indexes other than the primary key constraints. To facilitate joins, ProperyDetailsNew should probably have a composite clustered index on OwnerID and ID, with PK_NewPropertyDetails being non-clustered, and other indexes for common `WHERE` predicates. Otherwise, you'll likely get scans that may need a shared table lock for the duration of the query and block updates,